# Rich Snippets for Reviews and Ratings showing in Google (but not showing in Bing)

Tags: seo, rich-snippets, bing, schema.org

We just built structured content (review) by following the specification from Schema.org. We like our client website stand out with the rating (5 stars) on the search result.

So far this is working on Google. If you search for "hyundai high wycombe" on Google, you will able to see the 5 stars mark-up visual return from the search result. But, this is not working on Bing search engine.

We did check this with the Markup Validator on Bing webmaster tool for this URL http://www.hyundai.co.uk/dealer/platts-high-wycombe. We found everything look alright.

Any idea why the 5 stars for the URL above is not showing on the search result from Bing?[image]

Comment: I am not sure how long it has been. You may need to give Bing more time. Bing is not as dynamic as Google. I suspect that Bing is like Google in that they do not guarantee that rich snippets will show in the SERPs. Bing seems to be way behind the curve. It is a shame. Google needs competition and Bing is not bringing it on. Or should I say Bing is not *binging* it on??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bing and Google are two separate entities with different set of algorithms behind their search. I have also seen some rich snippets which show only on Bing only and not on Google. It's best to submit your website to Bing Webmaster Tools and then use the [Bing Markup Validator tool](http://www.bing.com/toolbox/markup-validator) to diagnose the problem (if any).

I have also experienced that Bing does not support all the rich snippet data types.